# Referencing CSS Sheet in Aspx page with Master Page

Tags: asp.net, css

Question is pretty well stated in the title. Normally I would use `<link... />` to reference my CSS Sheet but since I'm using a master page I don't have access to the `Head` Tag so how do I reference a specific CSS sheet on my ASPX page. I tried using `<%@ Import Namespace="Style.css"` but no luck. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add a CSS ContentPlaceHolder with a default value in it.

Basically, the CSS file you specify as default will be included unless you override that placeholder with an  tag from a child page.

**Your Master Page should look something like this.**

```
<head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Stylesheets" runat="server">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/master.css" type="text/css" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Then from any pages using that Master Page, you can simply override that with a different stylesheet.

**On (example) AboutUs.aspx**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Stylesheets" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/Style.css" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a CSS stylesheet to any ASPX page, you should use PlaceHolders.

Master page: (in the  section)

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

ASPX Page:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
// add your link here
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

just drag your style sheet to your master page.aspx and it will work for all your other forms

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 possible solutions:

1. Add your link to the head tag of the master page's markup. If you do so, all the pages using the given master page will automatically use your css file.
2. Use a ContentPlaceHolder in the head tag of your master page. You can use the ContentPlaceHolder at your pages referencing the given master page and you can add your link tag inside the ContentPlaceHolder tag in the markup.
3. You can add your link tag using Javascrip/jQuery functions.

Answer (score 0):

Although I went the code behind route below in my Page_Load event (VB), I'll give the correct answer to A.K as it seemed to answer the question better but just didn't suit my specific case.

```
Dim link As New HtmlLink()
link.Attributes.Add("href", Page.ResolveClientUrl("../Css/Generic-Form2.css"))
link.Attributes.Add("Type", "text/css")
link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet")
Page.Header.Controls.Add(link)
```

Answer (score -1):

Append the `link` tag to the `head` using DOM manipulation.