# Where do you add a link to CSS in a default ASP.NET Web Form?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I've just started to learn how to use ASP.NET, utilizing HTML/CSS. I've created a css file in my project that I would like to include in this html file, but I cannot seem to figure out where to include a link to my css.

I'm using the line `<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Default.css"/>` to link to my stylesheet.

This is my current code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MN.Resume.UI._Default" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Default.css"/>  
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <center><h1></h1></center>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <p style="font-size: 15px"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <p style="font-size: 15px"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <p style="font-size: 15px">(414) 550-4337</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <p style="font-size: 15px"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <center><p>Seeking a professional position as a Full Stack Developer.</p></center>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the dev tools console. It maybe a path issue. Try adding a leading / to the href like so, href="/CSS/Default.css"

Comment: `Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.

Source Error:


Line 1:  
Line 2:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Default.css"/>

Source File: /Default.aspx    Line: 2

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3429.0`

Comment: Sorry also add a tilde to the href for root path location --> href="~/CSS/Default.css"

Comment: Move the <link ... into the MasterPage inside the <head> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line including the link to the css should reside inside the content tag.

Here's an example [Referencing CSS Sheet in Aspx page with Master Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720576/referencing-css-sheet-in-aspx-page-with-master-page)